# How to identify users registering through Facebook and Google+ on an Android app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, google-signin

My android application has login functionality using Facebook and Google+. How can I identify users who have registered through this method and the normal users look up is done on the basis of user/pass and I am getting tokens in place of passwords here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users are logged into your app, I assume that you received access token, sent it to facebook/google and got profile information, right?

Somewhere in your database, where you keep your users, you have a table of users with a column "passwords". So query through this table. If password is null - notify. Else - don't notify.

Comment: Thanks Rex but the question here is about identifying users. Since email and password act as a unique combination to identify users. Users logging in using facebook and google+ have passwords as null so what unique identifier I should put in username field to identify them uniquely. Are the user ids provided by google and facebook static and unique for a given app.

Comment: The Ids are unique for google and facebook. Not for only your app, but for the whole service. So if you save an Id of user, this ID will point to the same user in every period of time.

Comment: Thanks Rex. I think I have got the answer to my question.